# react-native how to refresh when delete item on flatlist

Tags: react-native

i'm currently working on e-commerce app and in shopping cart i have some issues

to list the items i'm using FlatList and i'm keeping the shopping list items in asyncStorage to react out every screen in app.

my problem is when i add some items to asyncStorage and go to shopping cart screen it wont refresh the list automaticly and when i delete an item from list totalprice stay same  how could i manage that pls help me out

here is my code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window');

const Basket = ({navigation}) => {
  const [isData, setIsData] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [cartPrice, setCartPrice] = useState(0.0);

  useEffect(() => {
    getShoppingCart();
  }, []);

  const getShoppingCart = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('shoppingCart');
      if (jsonValue != null) {
        const result = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
        setItems(result);
        setIsData(true);
        if (items) {
          let totalPrices = 0.0;
          const totalPrice = items.map((item, i) => {
            totalPrices += parseFloat(item.price);
          });
          setCartPrice(totalPrices);
          console.log(cartPrice,'sepet tutarı')
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const clear = () => {
    setItems([]);
  };

  const remove = async index => {
    try {
      items.splice(index, 1);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(items));
      setItems(JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('shoppingCart')));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const emptyBag = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 40}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 22, marginBottom: 20}}>Your bag is empty</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>
          Looks like havent added any items to the bag yet. Start shopping to
          fill it in.
        </Text>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: '#0070FF',
            padding: 15,
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginTop: 20,
          }}>
          <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 16}}>START SHOPPING</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderItem = items => {
    //render item for flat list
    return (
      <View style={styles.wishproduct}>
        <Icon
          name={'minus-circle'}
          size={28}
          onPress={() => remove(items.item.id)}
        />
        <Text style={styles.productTitle}>{items.item.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.productPrice}>{items.item.price} USD</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', flex: 1}}>
      <View style={styles.title}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Sepetim</Text>
      </View>

      {items.length === 0 && emptyBag()}

      {items.length > 0 && (
        <>
          <View style={styles.subheader}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{marginLeft: 'auto'}}
              onPress={() => clear()}>
              <Text style={{color: '#ff3519'}}>Tümünü sil</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

          <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <FlatList
              style={{width: '90%'}}
              data={items}
              renderItem={item => renderItem(item)}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
              extraData={items}
            />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.subView}>
            <View style={styles.pricePiece}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 19}}>
                {'Ara Toplam (' + items.length + ' ürün):'}
              </Text>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 18}}> $ {cartPrice}</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Checkout')}
              style={styles.checkout}>
              <Text style={styles.checkoutText}>Alışverişi Tamamla</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Basket;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/async-storage-implementation) for this implementation. Check it out.

Firstly create a folder called `storage` where your `App.js` is located.

Inside that create a file called `storage.js`

Inside `storage.js` write this -

```js
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const StorageToken = "shoppingCart";

const storeData = async value => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(StorageToken, JSON.stringify(value));
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(StorageToken);
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
};

const removeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(StorageToken);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error in Removing token");
  }
};

export default { storeData, getData, removeData };
```

Then for `storing` data in any page You just have to do this

At the top `import Storage from "./storage/storage" // path to storage.js`

then, do `Storage.storeData(data) // This will stringify your data and store it`

**Now for your solution**

At the top `import Storage from "../storage/storage";`

Your `remove` function should look like this -

```js
const remove = async id => {
  try {
    let temp = [...items];
    temp = temp.filter(c => c.id !== id);
    setItems(temp);
    Storage.storeData(temp);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Your `getShoppingCart` function should look like this -

```js
const getShoppingCart = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await Storage.getData();
    if (jsonValue != null) {
      setItems(jsonValue);
      setIsData(true);
      if (jsonValue) {
        let totalPrices = 0.0;
        const totalPrice = jsonValue.map((item, i) => {
          totalPrices += parseFloat(item.price);
        });
        setCartPrice(totalPrices);
        console.log(totalPrices, "sepet tutarı");
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Your `clear()` function should look like this -

```js
const clear = () => {
  setItems([]);
  Storage.storeData([]);
  // You can also do Storage.removeData() here
};
```